# Can't update the file after deleting conflicted file (the local one) with TortoiseSVN

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, conflict

I'm using TortoiseSVN. Recently there is a file in conflicted state. I right click it, choose 'Edit conflict', then choose 'Delete local file'.

I thought after deleting the local file, I could update to get the file from SVN server. But the fact is that TortoiseSVN doesn't let me get the file on server down to my local computer.

TortoiseSVN just shows that there are no changes.

I need the latest version of that file from server!!!

Comment: Have you tried 'Update to HEAD' ? to go to the latest version again from Tortoise SVN server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the version of the server, the easiest way is to

1. revert your local copy (if there are any changes in that directory or below, you will loose these, but if that conflict is the only problem, it helps. To do that, do the following:

   - Select `Revert...` from the menu [image]
   - In the opening dialog, accept that the file is reverted.
2. You now have a local copy without changes, so there should be no conflict there.
3. Now update that file to the current state of the repository.

If that does not work for the file itself, try to to if for the directory where the file lays in. Normally, it should be possible for this  directory (with the conflicted state) to be reverted ...

I hope this order of actions works under any circumstances.

Comment: the file was deleted as mentioned in the question, i then drew it back from recycle bin, but now the the file becomes a 'not-yet-added' file, and thus tortoisesvn won't show the revert menu item to me. tortoisesvn now ignores it or something....

Comment: Add another possibility for the directory, not the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

For editing conflicts... You need to open Edit Conflict panel and select the portions of the code you want to keep.

In case you delete a file, try importing that file again. If it doesn't work you need to make a fresh working copy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the original local file is in your Recycle Bin, I would restore it. Then, try updating again, but this time say "resolve using theirs." It should replace your local copy with the head copy.

Comment: i draw the file recycle bin and put it back there, but now tortoisesvn ignores it, the file becomes a 'not-yet-added' file.